# Integration over Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can we integrate over non-orientable riemannian manifold?
If so, how do we do it?
Some references would be nice.
Thank you!

Comment: Using a partition of unity is highly recommended.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by using a [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold). See John Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* Chapter 16 for a good introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 3):

You must integrate what's called a *density*, rather than a differential form, over a non-orientable manifold. See, for example, this [short discussion](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/*diff_geometry%28II%29/2.26/density), [a short article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold), or section 8.2 of Marsden-Ratiu-Abraham's *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis, and Applications*, where they discuss how to generalize Stokes's Theorem to this situation.