# Parallelizable open dense subset and integration

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry* (2016), it is stated on page 8 that any manifold $M^n$ has an open dense subset $O$ with $TO=O\times\Bbb R^n$. Thus it is orientable and one may define the integral of functions on it using the Riemannian volume form of $O$ (with the inherited metric). Then, since $O$ differs from $M$ by a set of measure zero, one can reasonably define $\int_M$ by $\int_O$. This is especially useful if $M$ is nonorientble and one cannot define a Riemannian volume form on it.

I have never seen integration on nonorientable Riemannian manifolds defined this way. What is the proof of the existence of $O$?

Comment: This is the complement to the cut locus of a point. One more thing, you want O to have full measure we which is true in this case.

Comment: @studiosus Could you please give more details or a reference?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/is-every-compact-n-manifold-a-compactification-of-mathbbrn and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670036/worst-case-examples-of-non-differentiability-of-the-riemannian-distance-function/670090#670090

Comment: @studiosus I unfortunately don't see what this has to do with my question...

Comment: Any bundle over a contractible space is trivial; cut locus complement is contractible.

Comment: @studiosus I feel stupid, I don't see where in those links contractibility is proven.

Comment: By the definition, if $C(p)$ is the cut-locus of $p$ in $M$, there exists an open starlike (w/r to 0) domain $U$ in $T_pM$ such that $\exp_p: U\to M -C(p)$ is a diffeomorphism. Now, observe that $U$ is contractible, so is $M-C(p)$.

Comment: There is an alternative concept of integration on general (non-orientable) manifolds via densities. A Riemannian metric on any manifold actually defines a canonical density, so you can always integrate functions on a Riemannian manifold. (It is actually only true in the orientable case that you get a volume form.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363484/integration-over-riemannian-manifolds?rq=1

Comment: @AndreasCap By "I have never seen integration on nonorientable Riemannian manifolds defined this way," I meant "I have only seen integration defined on nonorientable Riemannian manifolds using densities."

Comment: In any case, there is nothing canonical about the diffeomorphism $TO\to O\times\mathbb R^n$ (just modify it by an arbitrary smooth map $O\to GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Hence there is nothing canonical about the resulting notion of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Triangulate the manifold, and remove the (n-1)-squeleton : you have a disjoint union of balls (interior of simplices). By the way, you do not need to remove this balls to define integration : just integrate your function on every simplex (with the use of a Riemanian metric) and sum up over the simplices. Note that Lebesgue measure of the boundary of a simplex is $0$.