# Are manifolds almost diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional compact connected orientable smooth manifold. Can we always find a diffeomorphism
$$M\setminus S_1\cong\mathbb{R}^n\setminus S_2$$
where $S_1\subset M$ and $S_2\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ are subsets of measure zero?

Comment: Put any (smooth) Riemannian metric on $M$ and let $S_1=\operatorname{Cut}(p)$...

Comment: This was discussed several times at MSE. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322027/how-much-of-an-n-dimensional-manifold-can-we-embed-into-mathbbrn?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/is-every-compact-n-manifold-a-compactification-of-mathbbrn?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838633/parallelizable-open-dense-subset-and-integration?noredirect=1&lq=1